# Reading cookie across directories

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, cookies

This is my JavaScript code I use to create my cookie............

```
document.cookie = "Name=" + Name + ";expires=Friday, 31-Dec-2011 12:00:00 GMT; path/";
```

I create it in www.example.com/folder/file.html and it works.

But I cant read the cookie from www.example.com/index.html or www.example.com/folder2/file2.html.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an error in how you set the path

```
 path/
```

should be

```
path=/
```

Also, the format for the expiration date is wrong - it should be like `Thu, 2 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC`, the same format that is returned by `new Date().toGMTString();`.

Comment: It might very well be the expiration date as my modified answer points out.

Comment: Actually the bizarro time format with the `-` and `GMT` is correct according to the original Netscape cookie specification (http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html). The output of `toUTCString` (which is the same as the deprecated `toGMTString`) didn't used to be accepted for cookie expiry dates by all browsers, though I believe modern browsers do also allow it.